# \newcommand with \hyperref

Tags: macros, hyperref

In multiple places in my document I use a \hyperref where the text says "See **Appendix D** for more information on..."; in the LaTeX code it looks like this: `See \hyperref[TargetRef]{Appendix \ref*{TargetRef}} for more information on...`

This works fine.  So to save typing, I'd like to create a \newcommand.  I set it up like this: `\newcommand{\linkrhb}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{#2 \ref*{#1}}`.

I intend to execute it like this: `See \linkrhb{TargetRef}{Appendix} for more information on...`

But the \newcommand definition is failing:

```
Runaway argument?
{\hyperref [##1]{##2 \ref *{##1}} \par \par \title {Process for Semi-\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

I haven't been able to see what I'm doing wrong.  Why won't LaTeX accept this \newcommand definition?

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in your `\newcommand` definition: `\newcommand{\linkrhb}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{#2 \ref*{#1}}}`

Comment: Dang!  I swear I counted HALF A DOZEN times!  Thanks.

Comment: You can delete this question.